# Why aren't functions like std::is_permutation() intrinsically unsafe?

Tags: c++, algorithm, security, stl

C and C++ programmers have taken a beating over the last decade or so for often failing to perform proper bounds checking, especially on strings. These failures have often resulted in deep security problems in major software products. Since buffer overflow insecurities became well-understood, the drive to institute proper bounds checking has pushed many programmers away from traditional buffer- and string-manipulation functions like `strcpy()` and `sprintf()` at least in part because of the tendency of these functions to invite buffer overflow problems by making assumptions about the size of the target buffer. One of the advantages of STL types like `std::string` and `std::vector` is their strong control of buffer access.

But one thing puzzles me. Many of the most widely-used functions in the `<algorithms>` C++ header seem to positively beg for overflow abuse: specifically, those functions that take a `begin` iterator (especially an InputIterator) without a matching `end` iterator. For example:

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator copy (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, OutputIterator result);

template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryOperation>
  OutputIterator transform (InputIterator first1, InputIterator last1,
                            OutputIterator result, UnaryOperation op);

template <class ForwardIterator1, class ForwardIterator2>
   bool is_permutation (ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                        ForwardIterator2 first2);
```

The last example—`is_permutation()` is especially instructive. `copy()` and `transform()` are well-understood, so that C++ programmers *should* know either to manually check the bounds of the output container before calling these functions *or* to use something like a `back_inserter` that ensures the output container grows as needed. Therefore, the case can be made that although `copy()` and `transform()` can be misused, anything can, and programmers are easily educated on best practices with functions like these.

`is_permutation()` is a trickier case. Just looking at the function declaration above, what would you assume about the size of the second range (the one that begins with `first2`)? Does the second range need to be the same size as the first one, or no smaller, or no larger? I'm betting that easy answers to these questions are not springing to your mind. The concept of a "permutation" is not as comfortable and familiar to most programmers as the concept of copying. It therefore seems relatively easy to get `is_permutation()` wrong and to overflow a buffer one way or the other.

"Look it up!" I hear you say. Well yes, of course. But if programmers remembered everything they should and looked up everything else then we wouldn't have bugs and security holes, would we?

Why, then, don't `is_permutation()` and similar functions (i.e. functions taking all input iterators but not a full begin-end iterator pair for every range) require a full begin-end pair for all input ranges? (Note that `lexicographical_compare()`, for example, *does* fulfill this requirement.) Are functions like `is_permutation()` actually not as unsafe as I'm imagining them to be?

Comment: Is this a question or a blog post?

Comment: BTW, I love [that ale](http://www.theakstons.co.uk/Ales/Old-Peculier/).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was going for a novel, but missed and hit a manifesto.

Comment: C and C++ traditionally eschew bounds checking for performance reasons, leaving it to the software developer to decide whether they need it or not.  As Stroustrup himself [once said](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#really-say-that), *"C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off."*

Comment: @Jon I like it so much I named myself after it. Kind of like Sting only... the opposite.

Comment: Tangentially:  "Intrinsically unsafe" is a bit of a misnomer.  You can pick just about anything in C or C++ --- even `gets()` --- and there will be a situation in which it's safe and appropriate to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++14, there are four iterator versions of `equal`, `is_permutation` and `mismatch` to address precisely this point.

Comment: A reference (e.g. section number in the current C++15 proposal or link to a proposed-wording document) would be useful.

Comment: [N3690](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf) 25.2.10 Mismatch [alg.mismatch], 25.2.11 Equal [alg.equal], 25.2.12 Is permutation [alg.is_permutation],

Answer (score 9):

Most of the language is inherently unsafe, it is up to the programmer to use it correctly. The programmer must know **before** calling the function whether the arguments being used are correct or not.

Additionally, in some cases like `copy` it enables the use of forward iterators on open ranges. For example:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));
```

There is no corresponding iterator to mark the end of the stream, and the stream really has no end, you can keep adding to it continuously.

Comment: The second part can also be done with a second end iterator - just always compare as `false`.

Comment: @Xeo: How would that help enforce the safety that the OP wants? After all, there is no difference between the current interface and using a fourth iterator that always compares false. Yes, I know, it would allow for safer checks in the rest of the cases... but the language is not there to babysit you, it is there to allow you to write the most efficient code possible (in the safer way possible, but priority is performance). You can build safety on top of performance, but you cannot build performance on top of safety.

Comment: Or my personal favourite, `std::back_inserter`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that introducing a *last* iterator on the second range for `is_permutation` would make the function any less unwieldy.  I think it would make it more confusing.

The thing with permutations is that the semantics are in the name itself.  To check that one sequence is a permutation of another, you expect the sequence with no *last* iterator to be at least as long as the first sequence.

If that's not the case, then you don't need to call `is_permutation` because it simply can't be a permutation.  If it's longer, you *expect* that it's not going to iterate past the length of the first sequence - why would it?  Well, it doesn't - and that's what you expected, so no faith is lost.

C++ does expect programmers to take basic precautions, and makes us responsible for bounds-checking in many cases.  Without giving that control to the programmer, the power of the language is diminished.  If I'm calling `is_permutation` then I *know* that my second iterator is not going to overflow, because I *know* what a permutation is.  I certainly don't want to waste cycles doing pointless bounds-checking.

I think the old saying applies: *With great power comes great responsibility*.  That's fair enough, isn't it?

Comment: I'd expect the second sequence to be exactly as long as the first one. If it were longer, it couldn't be a permutation. But that's a quibble: it's certainly possible that there are more elements available than are being used as the second sequence; whether those are *semantically* part of the conceptual sequence or not depends on your interpretation of what "the second sequence" refers to, exactly. IOW, if you didn't know the sequences were the same length, you should check that first before calling is_permutation. Seems like a simple rule.

Comment: `c++14` will add overloads taking a *last* for the 2nd range.

Comment: @rici There's actually no need to talk about the length of the second sequence, provided there are at least as many elements as the first.  You can test for smaller-length permutations inside a larger sequence without getting hung up on the fact that only `N` elements will be examined, where `N` is the length of the first sequence.  So it's more correct to say that the second sequence must contain *at least* as many elements as the first.

Comment: @paddy: like I said, I think its semantics. I would say that the *container* in which first2 exists needs to be big enough that `first2 + (last1 - first1)` is valid. However, the *range* which is being checked is precisely as long as the size of the first range, which might or might not be the entirety of a container. This is the same as std::equal, where it is clear that if you want to compare two entire containers for equality, you first have to compare their lengths before using calling std::equal. So the semantic question is whether "sequence" means "range" or "rest of the container".